# drag and drop display divs for form wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm new to jquery I wanted when onclick submit button whatever inside the droppable to display out what is been dropped inside, for now is whatever is drop inside will display out the ids but it is together.. I wanted them to display differently so I can put inside my form wizard step 1, 2 or 3.. Any ideas how to do that? please guide me along..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ww85n1n/)

**Javascript**

```
/* Drag and Drop */
$(function() {
  var countDropped = 0;
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    cursor: "move",
    cursorAt: {
      top: 56,
      left: 56
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
  });
  $('#reset').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropped_icon = $('#briefcase-droppable')
      .children()
      .detach()
      .removeClass('dropped end-draggable')
      .removeAttr('style')
      .css('position', 'relative');

     $('#dragIcons').append(dropped_icon);
     $('#briefcase').css('background', 'url("http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/Briefcase-12.png")');
  });
  $("#briefcase-full").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
      }
      countDropped++;
     ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var iconsid = " "
    $("#briefcase-droppable").children(".icons").each(function() {
    iconsid += $(this).attr("id");
    });
    $("#listicon").html(iconsid);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace script like this it will work

```
/* Drag and Drop */
$(function() {
  var countDropped = 0;
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    cursor: "move",
    cursorAt: {
      top: 56,
      left: 56
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
    }
  });
  $('#reset').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropped_icon = $('#briefcase-droppable')
      .children()
      .detach()
      .removeClass('dropped end-draggable')
      .removeAttr('style')
      .css('position', 'relative');

    $('#dragIcons').append(dropped_icon);
    $('#briefcase').css('background', 'url("http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/Briefcase-12.png")');
  });
  $("#briefcase-full").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
      }
      countDropped++;
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });

    $("#submit").click(function() { 
        $("#dragIcons").append($("#briefcase-droppable").html());
        $("#dragIcons").find('br').remove();
        $("#dragIcons img").after("<br />");    
        $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
    });



});
```

Comment: how do I list out one by one??

Comment: do you want to display one by on in dragIcons id?

Comment: yes that is what I want! one by one.. because when I display on divs on my code for now is display all dragicons id..

Comment: after click submit button it displays one by one.